# Teamcity build for live after successful CI build?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I have an environmental build system which currently has the following environments:

- dev
- ci
- uat
- live

Just to be clear when I say environmental build I mean there are a set of properties files for each environment and during the build these properties are used to template project files, so a database server may be "localhost" on dev environment but "12.34.56.78" on CI. So when starting the build you can give it an environment property and it will build for something other than dev (which is the default environment).

Now the CI build works fine and spits out the artifacts correctly, however as the build is CI all of it is configured to work on that environment, and I am looking at being able to trigger a build for live or uat when a CI build succeeds. This would then run the same build but with a different build argument.

Now I noticed there are a few mechanisms for this, one seems to be doing an automatic trigger on complete which could trigger another build, but this seems to require 2 separate build configurations which are essentially identical other than the build argument being "environment=live" rather than "environment=ci". Then there is adding another build step which would be the same as the first but take different argument and output the live artifacts elsewhere, but this would always happen much like the first option.

The final option I could see was to trigger a manual build once I have a *live candidate*, but it is unclear as to how to set a build argument, I could make a build parameter however it doesn't seem to get pulled into the build script like a command like build argument would.

Comment: After writing this I thought something seemed odd, and it ends up I can use build parameters within my project by using %environment% so using this method I can now do manual builds based off this, but still interested to see how others do it.

Comment: I do it using Build parameters, to specify target environment settings for the deployment. That way you can manually trigger a custom build through the UI, and specify all the required info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will see if there is a better answer, but after writing this I found that using Build Parameters seems the best option, this then can be embedded within your build configuration anywhere using the %environment% (or %your_parameter_here%).

This can then be setup to create a form element for manual builds so you can easily create a build for a different environments.